# MySQL query returning data with detailed / duplicated information

Tags: mysql

I am working on MySQL database, and I need to select some data with procedure. So I have something like:

```
CREATE TABLE pet (id INT, name VARCHAR(20), own_id INT);
insert into pet values (1,"Rufus", 1);
insert into pet values (2,"Bali", 1);
insert into pet values (3,"Lolo", 2);

ref pet.own_id = own.id 

CREATE TABLE own (id INT, own_name VARCHAR(20), own_color VARCHAR(20));
insert into own values (1,"Me", "Red");
insert into own values (2,"Other" ,"Green");
```

And now I wonder how to select / join data to get something like that (as results):

```
own_name    own_color   name
Me          Red         Rufus
Me          Red         Bali
Other   Green           Lolo
```

Comment: This is  a basic `join` query.  You should learn basic SQL if you are going to use the language.

Comment: I assume `own` means owner?

Comment: Gordon is correct that it's a simple join.  I've answered it below anyway.  But literally, any online SQL tutorial would cover this in the first section or two.

Comment: Shame on me. I've build query with statements, few joins, and I was wondering how to join data from additional table. Dunno why I just forgot how joins exactly works. Anyway I have to make review of some basic informations from SQL, especially those which ref to joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT own_name, own_color, name
from pet
JOIN own on (pet.own_id = own.id)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have only to join both tables:

```
Select own_name,own_color, name from own join pet on 
pet.own_id = own.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select o.own_name, o.own_color, p.name from own o, pet p
where p.own_id=o.id
```

It's a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

While a JOIN is a valid answer, some people find subqueries easier to read and write:

```
SELECT own_name, own_color, (SELECT name 
                             FROM pet 
                             WHERE pet.own_id = own.id) AS name
FROM own
```

This is basically the same as the JOIN method, but then as a subquery

I have a suggestion for your tables: own_id is a foreign key, so instead of

```
CREATE TABLE pet (id INT, name VARCHAR(20), own_id INT);
CREATE TABLE own (id INT, own_name VARCHAR(20), own_color VARCHAR(20));
```

I'd do:

```
CREATE TABLE own (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    own_name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    own_color VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE pet (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    own_id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    FOREIGN KEY (own_id) REFERENCES own (id)
);
```

I added some other things as well.

Improvements/changes:

- I assumed none of the fields should be NULL. I added NOT NULL to all the fields making it impossible for a field to have a value of NULL. (If you want some fields to be allowed to have a value of `NULL` just remove the `NOT NULL` from the `CREATE TABLE` statements.)
- I made both `id` fields increment automatically. This means the insert statements can now be just `insert into own (own_name, own_color) values ("Me", "Red");` and the database will automatically keep track of the ids for you.
- I added primary keys so the database knows that the rows can be identified by the `id` fields
- I added a foreign key constraint, meaning that every `own_id` in `pet` must exist in `own`. If you try to insert or alter a `pet` row in a way that breaks this constraint mysql will throw an error at you.